# how to setTemplate in loadLayout - action controller

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, template, magento-1

I try set my template in default layout, but it looks like:
[image]

How to move lower content blogpost.phtml?

I use this code in a controller action:

```
$this->loadLayout();
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('weblog/blogpost')->setSomething($data);
    $block->setTemplate('alanstormdotcom_weblog/blogpost.phtml');
    echo $block->toHtml();
    $this->renderLayout();
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you can do the following:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
```

So your final code will look like this:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('weblog/blogpost')->setSomething($data);
$block->setTemplate('alanstormdotcom_weblog/blogpost.phtml');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
$this->renderLayout();
```